# Ошибка при сложении чисел массива

Tags: java

Пытаюсь сложить числа в масиве и получаю ошибку в строке sum = sum + sum[i]; - Error:(80, 28) java: array required, but int found. Помогите разобраться!

int[] mas5 = {5, 3, 2, 8, 4, 1, -12, 3};

```
    int sum = mas5[0];

    for (int i = 1; i <= mas5.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + sum[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Наверное вы хотели `mas5[i]` а не `sum[i]`

---

P.S. К тому же надо или

```
i < mas5.length;
```

или

```
i <= mas5.length - 1;
```

Comment: `mas5[i - 1]` *(2 символа нужно...)*

Comment: @Igor, не, нулевой элемент в сумме уже есть. Это надо условие в цикле строгое сделать.